# Mimicking Java enums with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

We have a javascript application that connects to a java service. In our front end application, we try to align all constants with the service-side declarations (enums in this format: UPPER_SNAKE_CASE), but often times we need to format the constants into other cases, (Start case, camelCase, etc).

In an effort to make our constants usage and constants declarations more consistent, we currently have a setup that looks something like this

```
// Class definition
export default class BaseEnum {
  constructor (obj) {
    const { varName } = obj;

    this.snakeCase = obj.snakeCase  Case ? obj.snakeCase : lodash.snakeCase(obj.varName);
    this.camelCase = obj.camelCase ? obj.camelCase : lodash.camelCase(obj.varName);
    this.text = obj.text ? obj.text : lodash.startCase(lodash.lowerCase(obj.varName));
    this.upperSnakeCase = obj.upperSnakeCase ? obj.upperSnakeCase : lodash.upperCase(obj.varName).replace(/ /g, '_');
    // ... other formats etc
  }
}

// Declaring a enum class
export const SUNNY_DAY = new BaseEnum({ 
  varName: 'SUNNY_DAY',
  camelCase: 'sunnyDay', // if for some reason we want to override the camelCase, we do it here; camelCase: 'sunny'
  text: 'Today is a sunny day',
  upperSnakeCase: undefined // if left out, the class will generate the upperSnakeCase format
});


// In use
console.log(SUNNY_DAY.snakeCase);
console.log(SUNNY_DAY.camelCase);     // ... etc
```

However, most of the time we access the UPPER_SNAKE_CASE format, so we end up with this littered all over the places

```
console.log(SUNNY_DAY.upperSnakeCase);
```

Is there a way to mimic the Java internal toString magic in Javascript?

```
public enum SunnyDay {
  SNAKE_CASE('SUNNY_DAY'),
  CAMEL_CASE('sunnyDay'),
  TEXT('Today is a sunny day')

  private String description;

  public SunnyDay(String description) { this.description = description; }

  public String description() { return this.description; }

  // other overrides
}
```

**Question: Is there a way to use it in the below way instead, similar to Java?**

```
console.log(SUNNY_DAY); // default prints 'SUNNY_DAY', instead of the object
sout(SunnyDay.SNAKE_CASE); // 'SUNNY_DAY'
```

I've tried overriding the toString prototype, but that also requires calling SUNNY_DAY.toString(), which seems just about the same as calling SUNNY_DAY.upperSnakeCase. I can't think of a way using Javascript to do what Java does behinds the scene with its version of toString();

I've also tried creating some sort of abstract class to extend, but to no avail.

Any ideas? Is this even possible?